# How to kill a navigation stack? Pop all previous screens in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

So I have this kind of walkthrough that pushes the user from one screen to another (Six screens in total). In the last page, I would like the user to press "Done" and take him back to the first screen without being able to pop back to any of the previous screens.

Right now it will pop the last screen but not any of the other ones so it take me back to my original screen with the ability to pop back to the screen before the last screen (hopefully that last sentence makes sense to you, because the last screen was popped it takes me back to the screen before that one).

Any idea how to get around that?

Thanks!

Comment: For example https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator/popUntil.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To pop multiple screens from the navigation stack, like in your given scenario we can use [Navigator.popUntil](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator/popUntil.html). It takes a `BuildContext`and a `RoutePredicate` as parameters. The Navigator calls `pop` until the returned value by the given `RoutePredicate` is true.

Here is very basic example. It uses [ModalRoute.withName](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ModalRoute/withName.html) to create the `RoutePredicate`:

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        '/': (BuildContext context) => Home(),
        '/another': (BuildContext context) => Another()
      },
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Home'),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Take me to another screen!'),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/another'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Another extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Next screen.'),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/another'),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Pop em all.'),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.popUntil(
                    context,
                    ModalRoute.withName('/'),
                  ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

The method you are looking for is `popUntil()`, take a look at the implementation https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/popUntil.html or https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/popUntil.html

You will have to do probably something like

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName('/my-target-screen'));
```

(take a look at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ModalRoute/withName.html)

or use some custom function (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RoutePredicate.html).